# transition does not work with 100% width

Tags: css, width, transition

the transition doesn't work, maybe someone can help? 
i want that the width is as long as the text and no fixed width, 100% width doesn't work, where is the mistake?!
I set it the width to auto but than there is no transition...
http://jsfiddle.net/6Lso4jt1/

```
<a href="#" class="hotspot"><span class="hotspot-info">bsf ksv nvd</span></a>

.hotspot {
display: block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: #c23538;}

.hotspot:hover .hotspot-info {
width: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
display: block;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 10px;}

.hotspot-info {
position: absolute;
transition:width 100ms ease-in-out;
width: 0;
background-color: #c23538;
height: 40px;
color: white;
line-height: 40px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: apparently transitioning to/from width:auto [is not available](http://n12v.com/css-transition-to-from-auto/). Perhaps jQuery will be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transition-property to specify the css property.

```
transition-property: width;
-webkit-transition-property: width;
transition: 100ms ease-in-out;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lso4jt1/2/

*Another Way:*
use `transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;` and you won't need to specify the css property.

I hope this helps.